# How to setup a web page as fullscreen and lock the user to that screen until he presses a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullscreen

I am creating an examination application and while taking the examination, I want to lock the user to the web page and make him not able to navigate away unless they complete the quiz, i.e. by pressing a finish quiz button. I am using React to write the web application and I have seen some web applications do this, but I am not sure if they use an assistant desktop application to provide this functionality.

I have been reading up a bit and tried some libraries but they all let the user exit full screen using the F11 button. Is such a result actually possible using only a webapp?

Comment: I doubt this can be achived with any browser, it would be a very abusable behaviour. It should be possible wrapping the web app into some kind of minimal native app that consists of a giant webview.

Comment: You can launch fullscreen mode in a browser, but it's under the browser's control so you cannot prevent a user from exiting it, nor should you be able to.  If this functionality exists I'd suspect it's an application simulating a web browser.

Comment: I have used numerous applications which implement such this functionality and I specifically remember typing in the URL after launching Chrome. If, as you guys say, it is not possible, then they must have triggered such that a locked full screen is started when a certain 'Start Quiz' button is clicked